# Display Toggl time entries as a timeline

Tags: toggl

I am using Toggl and can't find a way to show my time entries chronologically.

In the desktop app and the website the entries are grouped by project.

I want a way to see my full day of work to check that I didn't forget the enter any time period. I am imagining something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I started poking around to see how hard it would be to use the API to create such a thing.   The first step of that is to get your API key from Profile Settings.   There I found a tick box for "Group Similar Time Entries".   Unticking this gave me what I was looking for when I found your question: Time Entries sorted chronologically so I can check for an unbroken chain to end-time to start-time being lined up.   It is not as fancy as what you describe but it might help while waiting for what you described.

- Page with the tick box: https://toggl.com/app/profile
- API Docs: https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs

  - Page for pulling time entries: https://github.com/toggl/toggl_api_docs/blob/master/chapters/time_entries.md
- The program that looked like it might get me close: https://github.com/kurtgn/chronicl/blob/master/chronicl.py